# Как можно повысить быстродействие программы? Не проходит тесты по времени

Tags: c++

На плоскости задана совокупность точек. Гарантировано, что разные точки совокупности действительно разные (никакая пара точек не совпадает). Напишите программу, которая находит минимальное среди всех расстояний между этими точками. (Иначе говоря - расстояние между парой ближайших точек). Расстояния считать в обычной Евклидовой метрике, как [image: формула]

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Dots {
    double x, y;
};

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    double result = 9999999999999999;
    double buff;
    vector<Dots> dotsarr(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> dotsarr[i].x >> dotsarr[i].y;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            buff = pow((dotsarr[i].x - dotsarr[j].x), 2) + pow((dotsarr[i].y - dotsarr[j].y), 2);
            if (buff < result) result = buff;
        }
    }

    printf("%.10f\n", sqrt(result));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [существуют алгоритмы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) со сложностью лучше `O(n^2)`

Comment: 1. координаты у тебя целые, потому считай в целых числах это быстрее.
2. корень считай только у ответа, а сравнивать можно суммы квадратов